# Why am I unable to assign a list like this to a jquery variable?

Tags: php, jquery

Why am I unable to assign a php variable like this to jquery?

So if my php variable was `$amounts = 2,4,5` and when I echo it is `2,4,5` why is it not the same when I pass it to a `jQuery` variable like this:

```
var amountFinal = <?php echo $amounts; ?>;
alert(JSON.stringify(amountFinal));
```

If I just do:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(<?php echo $amounts; ?>));, it prints `2`
```

All I want to do is pass `2,4,5` to amountFinal.

How do I do this? I am new to programming

ALSO, in php how do I break `2,4,5` into just `2`, `4`, `5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$amounts` is a string with commas in it so you need to make the javascript code legal and wrap it in quotes. Also as its a string and not valid JSON change the alert also.

```
var amountFinal = "<?php echo $amounts; ?>";
alert(amountFinal);
```

I dont understand what you mean by you second question?

ALSO, in php how do I break 2,4,5 into just 2, 4, 5?

Do you mean you want to make it into an array or you want to add some spaces?

To make `2,4,5` into `2 4 5` you can do

```
$originalString = '2,4,5';
list($one,$two,$three) = explode(',', $originalString);
echo $one;
echo $two;
echo $three;
```

Or add them to an array

```
$originalString = '2,4,5';
$array = explode(',', $originalString);
```

Comment: Thank you, so how do I break the `2,4,5` in php as just `2`  `4`   `5`?

Comment: Thats the only other thing I need help with sir

Comment: Sorry I meant how do you split the list and get individual numbers out of it?

Comment: Like how would I get just 2 on its own, 4 on its own and 5 on its own

Comment: sure, i think with those numbers i want to add them to a php array so like $newnum[0] = 2, $newnum[1] = 4

Comment: thanks so how would i add them to a new array? because sometimes i might have more than 3 numbers or less than 3 numbers